# No audio in my ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I am running ubuntu 9.10. But there is no sound in my environment.
When I go to System->Preference, there is no 'sound' entry there.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: I82801AAICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ lsmod
Module Size Used by
usb_storage 52576 3 
binfmt_misc 8356 1 
vboxvfs 34620 0 
vboxvideo 1884 1 
drm 159584 2 vboxvideo
agpgart 34988 1 drm
snd_intel8x0 30168 2 
snd_ac97_codec 101216 1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus 1532 1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm_oss 37920 0 
snd_mixer_oss 16028 1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_pcm 75296 3 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_dummy 2656 0 
snd_seq_oss 28576 0 
iptable_filter 3100 0 
snd_seq_midi 6432 0 
ip_tables 11692 1 iptable_filter
x_tables 16544 1 ip_tables
snd_rawmidi 22208 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event 6940 2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
ppdev 6688 0 
snd_seq 50224 6 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_mid i_event
snd_timer 22276 2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device 6920 5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi ,snd_seq
psmouse 56500 0 
serio_raw 5280 0 
snd 59204 14 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_ oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_ti mer,snd_seq_device
i2c_piix4 9932 0 
parport_pc 31940 0 
soundcore 7264 1 snd
snd_page_alloc 9156 2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
vboxguest 143836 7 vboxvfs
lp 8964 0 
parport 35340 3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
pcnet32 32644 0 
mii 5212 1 pcnet32
floppy 54916 0 
~:987:2$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 40)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB Controller: Apple Computer Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 0
00:0b.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
~:988:3$
```

Comment: `00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)` screams "hey there's a sound device found and detected!"

Have you tried simply playing audio?

Comment: +1 for including the command outputs you've examined so far

Comment: You can follow this tutorial: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with Ubuntu is that the volume settings sometimes drop to 0.
(don't know why)

But it is easy to check if this is your problem.

Start gnome-volume-control a make sure that volume is not 0 or muted.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well when I last upgraded Ubuntu to 9.10. In that case, there was no simple straight forward solution I could find on the net. I just re-installed and it worked like a charm.